# Is it possible to define derivative classes that are DataContract?

Tags: wcf

Is this code can be possible in WCF ? 
The object base and derivativeObject  are both object that will be send to the client. 
I tested this and i getting an exception - but i'm not sure this is something prohibition in WCF.

```
[DataContract]
public class base
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class derivativeObject : base
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking to use [Known Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) (and the [KnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx)) perhaps?

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(SalesPerson))]
public class Person
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SalesPerson : Person
{
  [DataMember]
  public double Commission { get; set; }
}
```